# Excel Conditional Formatting If Value Exists in Another Sheet Based on It's Quantity

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a document that uses two sheets. Inventory Mngmnt and Property Book.  I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the PRODUCT ID in the Property Book Sheet if it exists in the Inventory Mngmnt only if it has a QTY greater than 50. I know I can use use =ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,'Inventory Mngmnt'!C:C,0)) to highlight the Product ID in the Property Book Sheet, but have hit a brain block how to leave the 0 QTY unhighlited. Does this require a second rule to complete; and if so, could I get an example?  Below are OneDrive links to screenshots (JPEG) of the sample sheets as it would not let me embed photo's yet.

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ast64ku126VXzEICjsAwPM_eWFyk?e=elEe25

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ast64ku126VXzENLKZBOIK3OFIaq?e=WBZaEm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your `MATCH` tests only if there's a matching number. You need a rule that finds a matching invoice number, looks up the quantity, and tests it against your criterion.Try using `XLOOKUP()>50` as your conditional formatting rule. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

Comment: Xlookup worked beautifully. Thanks!